# Centering Div Element vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am working on a very basic website template with a fixed header at the top left and a fixed bottom line at the bottom left and right.

The content in the middle is supposed to be centered and I just can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong.

Question 1.) Why does vertical centering not work if I remove the `height: 100%` css property?

Question 2.) When `height: 100%` is declared on the html tag, why is the site bigger than 100% and extends beyond the browser window?

Question 3.) Why is `bottom-left` displayed correctly, but not `bottom-right`?

Question 4.) If with is set to 100% and text align to right, shoulnd't text start at the right browser frame and extend to the left? why is it extending the browser windows?

Thanks so much for helping out. Code is visible below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;‚
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Center Text Section */

.area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.middlespace {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: table;
}

.middlespace p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.exhibitionindex {
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.bottom-left {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}

.exhibitiontitle {
    color: #d4d4d4;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bold {
    font-family: serif;
}


.about {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.contact {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.openinghours {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 11px;
}

</style>

<title>Website Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">Logo / Title Text</div>

    <div class="area">
        <div class="middlespace">
            <p>27. April 2012</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
        <span class="about"><span class="bold">XYZ</span> is a project by Person One, Person Two, Person Three&nbsp;&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="contact">Website Information &mdash; <a href="mailto:info@info.com">info@info.com</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right"><span class="openinghours">Opening Hours Information</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you've got some extra curly brackets in there.  I would clean those up before doing anything else.

Comment: thanks Jeff! taken care of those.

Comment: This: `<span class="openinghours">Opening Hours Information/span` is not closed properly.

Comment: thanks for point this out Zulu

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1.) Why does vertical centering not work if I remove the
>   height: 100% css property?

By default, the `html` and `body` elements expand height to fit their content.  So, without setting the height, your `html` is only as tall as it needs to be to contain the content as styled.  In addition absolutely positioned elements do not affect the size of their parents.  Without setting the height to 100%, `area` will not be the full height of your window either, so you will be vertically centering in a small strip at the top of your page.

> Question 2.) When height: 100% is declared on the html tag, why is the
>   site bigger than 100% and extends beyond the browser window?

That alone will not extend beyond the page boundaries.  However, if you add margins, borders, or similar attributes to 100% elements, these are added *in addition* to the 100%, making your elements extend past the edge of the window.

> Question 3.) Why is bottom-left displayed correctly, but not
>   bottom-right?

You are absolutely positioning these elements.  Div elements are generally 100% the width of the parent element.  However, when you absolutely position them, their width shrinks to fit the content.  In your case, you are trying to `text-align` within a `div` that is left-aligned by default.  Because the `div` is only as big as the text, left, right, and center alignment all look the same.  Because you are already absolutely positioning the `div`s, just use absolute positioning to align them:

```
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: thanks jeff!

About Question 1:

I put margin-top/bottom: zero in the html tag which made the site not extend beyond the browser window again. I only defined margin-left:15% before though and wonder why this adds a marging to the bottom or top? or does the html always have small margin by default?

Comment: You have `margin-left: 20px;` in your body.  You probably shouldn't do this.  Instead, either do a padding, or just absolutely position your elements over 20px.  For instance, do `left: 20px` on your title.

Comment: And @Roland, each browser has a number of different default CSS definitions.  Usually the body has padding by default, along with a number of other styles that vary from browser to browser.  It is usually a good idea to "normalize" your CSS with a CSS reset stylesheet.  Here is one example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/